# List of components with their meanings published by a reliable source

Tags: simplified-characters, radicals, character-components

I want to learn more about the meaning of the radicals of simplified chinese characters, because I feel that by knowing what each radical means, I can have a better understanding of the meaning of the characters.

So, I want to find a list of radicals of Chinese characters along with their meanings. Through using a search engine, I was able to find some guides on this topic on the Internet. For example:

http://xh.5156edu.com/page/z2443m7618j19616.html (for convenience, see screenshot of the website below)

[image]

https://zhuanlan.zhihu.com/p/338926715 (for convenience, see screenshot of the website below)

[image]

However, I would rather read this information from a reliable source since that would be more reliable than reading an article published by someone on the Internet. Preferably, the information should be published by a public institution from China that is in charge of the regulation of Chinese characters (e.g. [Ministry of Education](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q1042167), [National Language Commission](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q10926073), I might be missing some). If this information is mentioned in a serious book, I would also be willing to read it.

I found a document called "The Table of Indexing Chinese Character Component" published by the "Ministry of Education of the People's Republic of China" [(link)](http://www.moe.gov.cn/jyb_sjzl/ziliao/A19/201001/t20100115_75694.html) that lists the radical but the list doesn't mention the meaning of each component.

Comment: I think you are having a naive, oversimplistic idea of our characters, like they are indexed by radicals and each radical forms a semantic field. No, the truth is far more complicated. That said, for a small number of radicals, the characters under that radical do have somewhat related meanings, and 王力古汉语字典 has a 部首总论 when this is the case. Again this is only for a very small number of radicals.

Comment: Remember, radicals are HUGELY different from components. Dictionary radicals are used for indexing characters in a dictionary. Components are more for referring to actual parts of a character. You shouldn't memorize all the dictionary radicals as this will hinder you from knowing the true role of each component in a character and this will lead up to some mistakes.

Comment: If I were to decompose let's say 法 (which is composed of 氵 (water, meaning component) and 去 (qù [not obvious sound connection in modern Chinese], sound component), I would end up making the wrong explaination saying "it is composed of the radicals 氵 (water), 土 (earth) and 厶 (private)". This will not help as you are hiding away the true meanings of the components and this will make it more harder to memorize.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this page [漢典 字典部首索引](https://www.zdic.net/zd/bs/).

Unlike what you requested, it doesn't give you a list of radicals with their meaning. It, however, gives you a list of all radicals with a link to all characters under each radical. The first character typically is the radical itself. You click the radical to get the meaning of that radical. This is a two-step process, not as convenient as the one-step process you requested.

If you want a list of radicals with their meaning, you'll have to compile it yourself.